# Set Theory - Elementary Question on Empty Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Ok so we are going to begin looking at Set theory next week in class so I thought I would try to learn a bit about it before we start. I am curious and perplexed by $(A \cap \emptyset)′$ in regard to what it can be simplified to as when using the rules of set theory.

For example if I have $U$ and $A$, $B$ are both subsets does that mean that $(A \cap \emptyset)′ = U$ or does 
$(A \cap \emptyset)′ = (A)'$?

If anyone can please provide some insight that would be much appreciated.

Comment: With θ do you mean the *empty set* : $\emptyset$ ?

Comment: The intersection of $\emptyset$ and $A$ whatever will be the set of common elements to $A$ and the empty set. But the  empty set has **no** elements at all.

Comment: by definition $A\cap\emptyset=\emptyset$ for any set $A$. What you mean by $'$? It is the complement, the derived set? If it is the complement then it depends on the space where the complementation is defined.

Comment: sorry, yes i meant the empty set and the ' was representing the compliment sorry I was just using the symbols in the text book